# Scrapy error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy `1.4`,the version of `twisted` is `17.5.0`,python is `3.6.3`.

html is like this：

```
<span class="number">   20</span>
```

when I run the spider,there is an error:

```
item['number'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="number"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

what should I do?

Comment: Your extract_first() function most likely returns a None element in this specific case. Either validate what you return in the function code in a try/except block and exit there if you can't get a value you can pass to another function, or validate the answer before assignment so your strip() doesn't error out on unexpected None typed objects. I would do it before assignment as maybe you want extract_first to return None sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like problem is in the xpath that you wrote or in the document itself. `extract_first` method returns `None` if no match found. I've checked your example in online xpath validators and seems like everything is fine